# How to merge multiple sorted ranges in c++?

Tags: c++, merge, array-algorithms

`std::merge` performs the merge operation on two sorted ranges. I have N (>>2) sorted ranges and I would like to merge them into one sorted range.

The obvious way is to use `std::merge` N-1 times. I am wondering if there is a better algorithm in C++ std library.

Comment: `std::reduce` which operates on ranges with binary operation being the `std::merge` perhaps could be what you are looking for. But it will require some wrappers, because std::merge does not have only two arguments.

Comment: Think about the performance implications of doing an N-way merge, versus multiple well chosen 2-way merges.  For additional insight, look at your library's `std::list::sort` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume each range is roughly the same size and there are M items total, then `std::sort` will give you the right answer in O(M log M) time versus O(M^2) for naive repeated merges. I feel like the right answer is to bisect the full range and call `std::merge` in a tree. If we assume each range is about the same size and that they are contiguous and that we have a range of iterators pointing to them, I think this is the right way: https://godbolt.org/z/GudjnM

```
// In-place merge multiple contiguous ranges.
// Could probably get better cache coherency
// if it merged lazily (depth-first traversal
// rather than breadth-first).
template <typename IterIter>
void multi_inplace_merge(const IterIter begbeg, IterIter endend) {
    while (std::distance(begbeg, endend) >= 3) { // There's work to do.
        auto output = begbeg; // We'll overwrite with the new ranges.
        auto it = begbeg;
        for (; it != endend && it + 1 != endend; it += 2) {
            if (it + 2 != endend) { // There's something to merge.
                std::inplace_merge(it[0], it[1], it[2]);
                *output = it[0];
                ++output;
                *output = it[2];
                ++output;
            } else {
                *output = it[1];
                ++output;           
            }
        }
        endend = output;
    }
}
```

For example

```
    std::vector<int> x = {1, 10, 100,   0, 9,  -1,5, 1000, 10000, 9999999};
    std::vector<decltype(x)::iterator> its = 
      {x.begin(), 
       x.begin() + 3, 
       x.begin() + 5, 
       x.end()};
    multi_inplace_merge(its.begin(), its.end());
    for (auto y : x) {
        std::cout << y << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
```

produces

```
-1, 0, 1, 5, 9, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 9999999,
```